# Why do correlated subqueries which use MAX return multiple rows?

Tags: mysql

When executing the following mysql command, it appears that the correlated subquery
returns multiple rows.

Question 1.  Why is MAX able to return multiple rows? 
Question 2.  How can the '=' operator be used to match multiple rows?

```
SELECT Continent, Name, Population 
FROM Country c 
WHERE Population = (SELECT MAX(Population) 
                    FROM Country c2 
                     WHERE c.Continent=c2.Continent AND Population > 0);


+---------------+--------------------+------------+
| continent     | name               | population |
+---------------+--------------------+------------+
| Oceania       | Australia          |   18886000 |
| South America | Brazil             |  170115000 |
| Asia          | China              | 1277558000 |
| Africa        | Nigeria            |  111506000 |
| Europe        | Russian Federation |  146934000 |
| North America | United States      |  278357000 |
+---------------+--------------------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.22 sec)
```

Comment: Actually it returns the highest population for every continent. are you expecting to return the continent which has the highest pupulation?

Comment: I'm expecting it to return the population of one country that has the highest population of all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[from your comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442254/why-do-correlated-subqueries-which-use-max-return-multiple-rows/20442357#comment30539031_20442254), this query is the one you are looking for. This handles duplicates.

```
SELECT Continent, Name, Population 
FROM Country c 
WHERE Population = (SELECT MAX(Population) FROM Country)
```

The other query, *doesn't handle duplicate*

```
SELECT Continent, Name, Population 
FROM Country c 
ORDER BY Population DESC
LIMIT 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*difference of the two queries*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96e7c/1)

Comment: Let me rephrase.  I don't understand why my query is able to return the highest population of each continent.  Doesn't max return only one?

Comment: @TokyoMike because it is correlated with each other. meaning you are getting the highest value for every continent because of the condition `... WHERE c.Continent=c2.Continent`

Comment: @今 草 顿 웃 If it read WHERE c.Continent IN ('Oceania','North America') then MAX would return only one value.  Why is this case different?

Comment: `WHERE c.Continent IN ('Oceania','North America')` -- there is no subquery. In your case you are linking the outer query in your subquery but by removing this condition, `WHERE c.Continent=c2.Continent`, in your subquery will result the maximum value of all records.

Comment: Why does linking to the outer query cause MAX to be executed multiple times?

Comment: @TokyoMike: that's the definition of correlated subqueries. They are executed for every row in the containing virtual table. A correlated subquery is basically a for-loop, if you are familiar with regular programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that this part:

```
WHERE c.Continent=c2.Continent AND Population > 0);
```

Is making the outer query return every continent in country table, and the country with highest population (by means of the MAX(population) you do in the INNER query).

The `=` works in this case because the subquery only returns one row for each continent, but in the end you will still end up with results for every continent, and not the country with max population overall.

It's the same thing as doing:

```
SELECT Continent, Name, Population 
FROM Country c 
WHERE c.Continent = 'Oceania' 
   AND Population = (SELECT MAX(Population) 
                     FROM Country c2 
                     WHERE c2.Continent = 'Oceania' AND Population > 0);
```

But since you don't restrict the Continents to a specific one, it does the same thing for every continent in the table.

If you want to return only the country with MAX population you can do:

```
SELECT Continent, Name, Population 
FROM Country c 
ORDER BY population DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: If I were using IN instead of =, this would make sense. In fact, using IN returns the same results as =.  I just don't understand why they do.

Comment: Of course you would. The thing that makes you get multiple results is the correlation with the outside query. You are telling the inner query that you want the max population for the continent that you are seeing in the outer query. doing in or = is the same, because you get only one row for each continent. and that is the country in that continent with max(population)

Comment: If I were to rewrite with ...Population = (111,222,333) an error would occur. So in this case, is the = statement just being executed multiple times?

Comment: Nop. That's just a datatype error. either you use an integer or use '' around a string. e.g.INT: population = 111222333; string: population = '111,222,333'. That query will return the countries that have that population.

Comment: That was a bad example. Sorry.  I meant to show multiple values being on the right side of the = operator which should cause this error:

ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: That is a normal error. When you use = it can only have one result in each side of the =. Your inner query only returns one row in the original because you are telling it to get the MAX population for the Continent that you are in the outer query.

Comment: I was a bit confused about order of operation. siride mentions below that a correlated subquery executes like a for loop by comparing each value of the outer query. In that case, I can see how only one value is returned, thereby allowing the = operator to work. Thanks for your help!